# Change default polymorphism in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring

I'd like to set `polymorphism="explicit"` property to several hibernate mapping classes. is it possible to override the default `implicit` value, so that I do not need to set `explicit` in multiple classes?

```
<class name="xxxxx" table="XXXXX" polymorphism="explicit">
```

I am using hibernate mapping xml files (No annotations or JPA) and it was loaded by Spring as follows,

```
<bean id="xxxsessionFactory"   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="xxxDataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>xxx.hbm.xml</value>
            --------
            --------
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
            ----
            ----
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Browsing around the hibernate sources, it looks like there is no way to get around this limitation.

The hibernate core classes seem to determine the *polymorphism* setting by calling various `isExplicitPolymorphism()` methods, which all seems to boil down to [`org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.isExplicitPolymorphism()`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-core/blob/3.6.1.Final/core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/mapping/PersistentClass.java#L250) method. The value returned from this method is set at [`org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.setExplicitPolymorphism()`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-core/blob/3.6.1.Final/core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/mapping/RootClass.java#L192) method. This method is called only from [`org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues()`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-core/blob/3.6.1.Final/core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/HbmBinder.java#L367) (for XML configuration) and [`org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.bindEntity()`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-core/blob/3.6.1.Final/core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/annotations/EntityBinder.java#L223) (for annotation configuration) methods.

I don't see a way by which to set `ploymorphism=explicit` for all entities in a mapping file.